# Android: dynamically set the position of button into center of screen in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, position, android-relativelayout

There has been many questions on dynamically setting the position of a button, but I just want to change the position of a button into center of the screen. My layout is RelativeLayout.

**Updated:**

At the beginning, myButton has been set position in XML as:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Menu" />
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See an example below (click the button and it will be moved to the center).

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/my_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Menu" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private View mView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mView = findViewById(R.id.my_view);
        mView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams vg_lp = mView.getLayoutParams();

                // Make sure we are in RelativeLayout
                if (vg_lp instanceof RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) {
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rl_lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(vg_lp);
                    rl_lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
                    mView.setLayoutParams(rl_lp);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I assign my current view as my_view, but the button still does not move. It remains in the same place as in XML above

Comment: @DavidNg, I have edited my answer and added full code listing. It works for me. Try one again or post your full code listing.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
      ......
      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams();
      layoutParams.leftMargin = parentLayout.getWidth()/2;
      layoutParams.topMargin = parentLayout.getHeight()/2;
      button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
      ......
```

Comment: I set: RelativeLayout parentLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.layout.mylayout); with your code, my program crash. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
   RelativeLayout RL = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
   RL.gravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

with this all subviews of RL will be in center;

```
   Button anyButton = new Button(this);
   RL.addSubview(anyButton);//this genereted button will be in center as well
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this 2 lines to the component you want to center in the xml file :

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
RelativeLayout my_layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
my_layout.setId(some_value);
Button my_btn = new Button(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams my_params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(btn_height,btn_width);
my_params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT,my_layout.getId());
my_layout.addView(my_btn,my_params);
```